# TYPO3 meta.viewport not on subpages

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have created a TYPO3 webpage with subpages.

rootpage
-subpage1
--subpage1A
--subpage1B
-subpage2
--subpage2C

in the template of rootpage I added the following template

```
 page = PAGE
 page.includeCSS {
      file1=fileadmin/projectTemplate/bootstrap.min.css
      file2=fileadmin/projectTemplate/projectstylesheet.css
 }
 page.includeJS {
      file1=fileadmin/projectTemplate/bootstrap.min.js
      file2=fileadmin/projectTemplate/jquery.min.js
 }
 page.config.doctype=html5
 page.meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1
 page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
 page.10 {
 file = fileadmin/projectTemplate/index.html
      partialRootPath = fileadmin/projectTemplate/Partials/
      layoutRootPath = fileadmin/projectTemplate/Layouts/
      settings.layout = Nuremberg
 variables {
      content < styles.content.get
      contentRight < styles.content.getRight
 }
 }
 #we also create a typoscript-menu
 lib.menu = HMENU
 lib.menu{
   1 = TMENU
   1.NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
 }
```

The key here is `page.meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1`. On the root page it results in `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in the head section of the page. However on all subpages this meta viewport is not rendered.
The typo3 version is a plain 8.7.12 with no added or custom extensions.
The workaround is to put the `page.meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1` as an extension template on every subpage. This is somehow quite an overhead. Is there any possibility to avoid this?

Comment: this behavior is really really weird, and I am not able to reproduce it on a fresh 8.7.12 without extensions. Before trying something else, can you click on one of the subpages and then, using the Template module, navigate with TypoScript Object Browser to see the value of page.meta.viewport? Look also for TypoScript errors

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RiccardoDeContardi Now when I remove the custom template extension the site is rendered fine. So maybe the problem is to add this meta information after creating and rendering the pages (I always reloaded the pages with CTRL+SHIFT+R to circumvent browser cache)?

Comment: To clarify the problem, after creating and viewing the sites I added the ` page.meta.viewport = width=device-width, initial-scale=1` information to the template. It seems that this information was not propagated for at least some time. Is there some TYPO3-internal caching in place?

Comment: if you added it in the "setup" field of the template, the change should be immediately visible; if you add your typoscript in external files, then you have to clear the frontend cache.